# Secure websocket connection fails on iOS due to BoringSSL certificate verification failure

Tags: ios, nginx, websocket

I'm unable to connect to a secure websocket connection due to the following error on iOS (12 & 13).

It seems there is a failure validating the certificate for the end-point but I can't find a way to determine the reason. I can connect to the websocket end-point from a browser client. I also verified the certificate using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and don't see any issues. The SSL certificate is issued from Let's Encrypt.

Below is the console output I could capture from the device and console app on my mac laptop:

**XCODE DEBUG CONSOLE**

```
2020-04-29 16:18:03.501170-0700 [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(1873) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] write alert, level: fatal, description: certificate unknown 
2020-04-29 16:18:03.501366-0700 [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(1863) boringssl ctx 0x282eb41b0: 4450062232:error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-283.102.1/ssl/handshake.cc:369: 
2020-04-29 16:18:03.510648-0700 [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(164) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] SSL library error 
2020-04-29 16:18:03.510740-0700 [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(111) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] 4450062232:error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-283.102.1/ssl/handshake.cc:369: 
2020-04-29 16:18:03.510837-0700 [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(726) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] handshake failed at state 12288 
2020-04-29 16:18:03.532541-0700 [strings] ERROR: Network.NWError not found in table Error of bundle CFBundle 0x109308b40 </System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework> (framework, loaded) 
 error: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (NETWORK.NWERROR error 2.)")
```

**MAC CONSOLE APP**

```
default 16:18:03.712414-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: waiting for data to read [2]
default 16:18:03.712477-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: waiting for data to read [2]
default 16:18:03.712583-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: waiting for data to read [2]
default 16:18:03.712646-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: waiting for data to read [2]
default 16:18:03.712707-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Reading SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE 122 bytes
default 16:18:03.713628-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_hello_retry_request
default 16:18:03.713687-0700    boringssl_context_add_handshake_message_pending(578) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Adding message(2)
default 16:18:03.713747-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Writing SSL3_RT_CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC 1 bytes
default 16:18:03.713807-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_server_hello
default 16:18:03.713865-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_encrypted_extensions
default 16:18:03.714153-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Reading SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE 10 bytes
default 16:18:03.714219-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_certificate_request
default 16:18:03.714277-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Reading SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE 3105 bytes
default 16:18:03.714335-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_server_certificate
default 16:18:03.714395-0700    boringssl_context_info_handler(1983) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Client handshake state: TLS 1.3 client read_server_certificate_verify
default 16:18:03.714452-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Reading SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE 264 bytes
default 16:18:03.714628-0700    boringssl_context_copy_peer_sct_list(1003) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] SSL_get0_signed_cert_timestamp_list returned no SCT extension data
default 16:18:03.714914-0700    boringssl_helper_create_sec_trust_with_certificates(607) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] SecTrustCreateWithCertificates result: 0
default 16:18:03.714973-0700    boringssl_helper_create_sec_trust_with_certificates(612) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] SecTrustSetOCSPResponse result: 0
default 16:18:03.715033-0700    boringssl_helper_create_sec_trust_with_certificates(621) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] No TLS-provided SCTs
default 16:18:03.715167-0700    boringssl_context_certificate_verify_callback(2071) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Asyncing for verify block
default 16:18:03.715225-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: certificate evaluation result pending [16]
default 16:18:03.715418-0700    boringssl_context_certificate_verify_callback(2040) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Verification already in progress.
default 16:18:03.715481-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: certificate evaluation result pending [16]
default 16:18:03.716084-0700    boringssl_context_certificate_verify_callback(2040) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Verification already in progress.
default 16:18:03.716145-0700    boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(170) [C12.1:1][0x1151122e0] Handshake incomplete: certificate evaluation result pending [16]
default 16:19:16.180121-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C6.1:2][0x11321ccb0] Writing SSL3_RT_ALERT 2 bytes
default 16:19:16.180202-0700    boringssl_context_handle_warning_alert(1893) [C6.1:2][0x11321ccb0] write alert, level: warning, description: close notify
default 16:19:16.180285-0700    boringssl_session_disconnect(504) [C6.1:2][0x11321ccb0] SSL_shutdown 0
default 16:19:16.181104-0700    nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler(1012) [C6.1:2][0x11321ccb0] nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler forced true
default 16:19:16.181169-0700    nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler(1030) [C6.1:2][0x11321ccb0] Transferring nw_protocol_boringssl_t handle back into ARC for autorelease
default 16:19:33.510159-0700    boringssl_context_message_handler(2258) [C8.1:2][0x11328fd50] Writing SSL3_RT_ALERT 2 bytes
default 16:19:33.510247-0700    boringssl_context_handle_warning_alert(1893) [C8.1:2][0x11328fd50] write alert, level: warning, description: close notify
default 16:19:33.510309-0700    boringssl_session_disconnect(504) [C8.1:2][0x11328fd50] SSL_shutdown 0
default 16:19:33.510922-0700    nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler(1012) [C8.1:2][0x11328fd50] nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler forced true
default 16:19:33.511105-0700    nw_protocol_boringssl_remove_input_handler(1030) [C8.1:2][0x11328fd50] Transferring nw_protocol_boringssl_t handle back into ARC for autorelease
```

The NGINX server block for the end-point is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name me.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/me.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/me.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/me.example.com/chain.pem;

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://upstreamserver;

        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is an issue on iOS? I also posted this in [Apple's Dev Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132286)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a mis-configuration in the SSL certificate issued by LetsEncrypt and the NGINX setup. Due to [Apple's Certificate Transparency Policy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205280), there is now stricter certificate verification on iOS. Got a [good answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132286) on the Apple dev forums that helped trace the problem to the following:

1. Certificate issued by LetsEncrypt was missing embedded Signed Certificate Timestamps (SCT). I had to re-create my certificate with "OCSP Must Staple" support:

   ```
   certbot --nginx --hsts --staple-ocsp --must-staple -d domain.example.com
   ```

   To verify embedded SCT's are created for the certificate you can run `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text` and the output should contain something similar to:

   ```
   Certificate:  
       Data:  
           X509v3 extensions:  
               Authority Information Access:  
                   OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org  
                   CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/  

           TLS Feature:  
               status_request  
           X509v3 Certificate Policies:  
               Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1  
               Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1  
                 CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org  

           CT Precertificate SCTs:  
               Signed Certificate Timestamp:  
                   Version   : v1 (0x0)  
                   Log ID    : 5E:A7:73:F9:DF:56:C0:E7:B5:36:48:7D:D0:49:E0:32:  
                               7A:91:9A:0C:84:A1:12:12:84:18:75:96:81:71:45:58  
                   Timestamp : May  1 21:02:14.817 2020 GMT  
                   Extensions: none  
                   Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256  
                               30:45:02:20:2F:2C:22:85:50:DD:FD:DA:62:E9:60:BA:  
                               95:6C:49:03:1E:9E:F9:6C:9F:AA:A0:17:65:7F:D7:D3:  
                               A4:E7:CC:02:02:21:00:D4:2F:55:CF:F6:57:AC:BF:3E:  
                               E5:8B:F5:A2:00:47:2D:C4:5E:A4:10:EE:D7:D6:B4:FF:  
                               9E:21:1D:CC:6A:89:53  
               Signed Certificate Timestamp:  
                   Version   : v1 (0x0)  
                   Log ID    : 07:B7:5C:1B:E5:7D:68:FF:F1:B0:C6:1D:23:15:C7:BA:  
                               E6:57:7C:57:94:B7:6A:EE:BC:61:3A:1A:69:D3:A2:1C  
                   Timestamp : May  1 21:02:14.843 2020 GMT  
                   Extensions: none  
                   Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256  
                               30:44:02:20:17:63:1D:8E:76:CA:E0:A2:5C:42:92:7C:  
                               BC:06:60:C7:9B:46:BB:59:63:8F:E1:8A:BE:52:CB:15:  
                               FD:C4:DE:09:02:20:28:EF:48:E1:4B:BD:9D:05:29:52:  
                               FC:D9:5A:8B:82:08:9D:1A:A0:58:F0:33:FB:05:5E:E7:  
                               56:A0:AE:64:84:C7
   ```
2. NGINX server block needed proper OCSP configuration, remove HTTP/2 support, and use a cert chain that has the intermediate certificates and embedded SCT's

   ```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {  
        default upgrade;  
        '' close;  
    }  

    upstream ws-signal {  
        server localhost:8080;  
    }  

   server {  
       listen 443 ssl;  
       listen [::]:443 ssl;  
       server_name domain.example.com;  

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot  
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot  

       # OCSP Stapling  
       ssl_stapling on;  
       ssl_stapling_verify on;  
       ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.example.com/fullchain.pem;  
       resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;  

       location /ws {  
           proxy_pass http://ws-signal;  

           proxy_http_version      1.1;  
           proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
           proxy_set_header        Connection $connection_upgrade;  
           proxy_set_header        Host $host;  
       }  
   }
   ```

I also had to upgrade [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) to v4.0.3. This latest version uses URLSessionWebSocketTask for iOS 13+ and for iOS 12 seems to be overriding the verification to return true if certificate pinning is disabled. Still need to try with cert pinning enabled to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a class to help with sockets and the new apple TLS restrictions (see my readme). You are most likely misconfiguring your certificates. Along with my helper class that handles the socket, I tried to also layout how to create certificates that will work as of the new iOS TLS restrictions.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets